# "No such file or directory" when building Docker image

Tags: python, docker, build, dockerfile

I have an existing and working Dockerfile, that I want to update to have a better structure, and to allow me to volume-mount part of the application directory to enable persistence.

Folder structure is:

```
.git/
.gitignore
Dockerfile
README.md
Sorter.py
WebService.py
requirements.txt
```

The current working Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
ADD . /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "python", "./WebService.py" ]
```

I now want to simply do this not in the root directory, so I do the following:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["WebService.py"]
```

I build the image "docker build -t , and run it using the same docker-compose file as for the first buildscript - and I get the error:

```
"python: can't open file '/app/WebService.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "python", "./WebService.py" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line `WORKDIR /app`, as you can see the Docker tries to run the file `/app/WebService.py`, but you do not have it. Your file is in `.` not in `app` folder. So either you should create the `app` folder and put your `WebService.py` in that folder, either just remove `WORKDIR /app`.

Comment: but without the WORKDIR command, I'll end up dumping all the files in /root, which I don't want, as I would like to be able to do a volume-mount on the running container afterwards, which I believe advisable (or maybe even possible). Could you propose a working Dockerfile in which the applications files will be put in the "app/" directory and run from there? @razmik-melikbekyan

Comment: Try:

```
COPY . /
WORKDIR /
```